# Convert pandas.DataFrame to list of dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, json, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have a dictionary which is converted from a dataframe as below :

```
a = d.to_json(orient='index')
```

Dictionary  :

```
{"0":{"yr":2017,"PKID":"58306, 57011","Subject":"ABC","ID":"T001"},"1":{"yr":2018,"PKID":"1234,54321","Subject":"XYZ","ID":"T002"}}
```

What I need is it be in a list, so essentially a list of dictionary.
So i just add a [] because that is the format to be used in the rest of the code.

```
input_dict = [a]
```

input_dict  :

```
['
{"0":{"yr":2017,"PKID":"58306, 57011","Subject":"ABC","ID":"T001"},"1":{"yr":2018,"PKID":"1234,54321","Subject":"XYZ","ID":"T002"}}
']
```

I need to get the single quotes removed just after the [ and just before the ]. Also, have the PKID values in form of list.

How can this be achieved ?

Expected Output :

```
[ {"yr":2017,"PKID":[58306, 57011],"Subject":"ABC","ID":"T001"},"1":{"yr":2018,"PKID":[1234,54321],"Subject":"XYZ","ID":"T002"} ]
```

NOTE : The PKID column has multiple integer values which have to come as a lift of integers. a string is not acceptable.
so we need like "PKID":[58306, 57011] and not "PKID":"[58306, 57011]"

Comment: "What I need is it be in a list, so essentially a list of dictionary" : sorry but this is not enough to warrant the right answer - please post the _exact_ result you expect.

Comment: Thanks for highlighting it Bruno, I have now added expected results.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`pandas.DataFrame.to_json` returns a string (JSON string), not a dictionary. Try [`to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) instead:

```
>>> df
   col1  col2
0     1     3
1     2     4
>>> [df.to_dict(orient='index')]
[{0: {'col1': 1, 'col2': 3}, 1: {'col1': 2, 'col2': 4}}]
>>> df.to_dict(orient='records')
[{'col1': 1, 'col2': 3}, {'col1': 2, 'col2': 4}]
```

Comment: Thanks, is there also a way to NOT have index values in and in the same format ?
like just :
['
{"yr":2017,"PKID":"58306, 57011","Subject":"ABC","ID":"T001"},{"yr":2018,"PKID":"1234,54321","Subject":"XYZ","ID":"T002"}
']

Comment: @ShankarPandey I added another example

Comment: Thanks.
Is there a way to also make one column values as a LIST.
so if col2 had 2 integers seperated by comma, how would we make that an example below :
[{'col1': 1, 'col2': [3, 4] }, {'col1': 2, 'col2': [5,6] }]

Comment: @ShankarPandey Just iterate through the list and transform your values: `d['PKID'] = list(map(int, d['PKID'].split(',')))`

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

d = {"0":{"yr":2017,"PKID":"58306, 57011","Subject":"ABC","ID":"T001"},"1":{"yr":2018,"PKID":"1234,54321","Subject":"XYZ","ID":"T002"}}

list(OrderedDict(sorted(d.items())).values())

# [{'ID': 'T001', 'PKID': '58306, 57011', 'Subject': 'ABC', 'yr': 2017},
#  {'ID': 'T002', 'PKID': '1234,54321', 'Subject': 'XYZ', 'yr': 2018}]
```

Note the ordered dictionary is ordered by text string keys, as supplied. You may wish to convert these to integers first before any processing via `d = {int(k): v for k, v in d.items()}`.

Comment: dicts are unordered, so this won't preserve the (eventual) ordering implied by the keys... Might or not be an issue for the the OP...

Comment: Close but not quite there - here the keys are strings so you'll get lexical ordering (ie : `sorted(["1", "2", "10", "11"])` => `['1', '10', '11', '2']`). You want to convert keys to ints before IMHO ;)

Comment: As I originally mentionned : this "Might or not be an issue for the the OP"  - but we actually don't know since the OP didn't post the exact expected output (and obviously everyone interpreted it differently) ;) I only wanted to make clear that your first solution would eventually loose ordering and that the second would use lexical ordering instead of numerical ordering, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

You are converting your dictionary to `json` which is a string. Then you wrap your resulting string a list. So, naturally, the result is a string inside of a list.

Try instead: `[d]` where `d` is your raw dictionary (not converted `json`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension

**Ex:**

```
d = {"0":{"yr":2017,"PKID":"58306, 57011","Subject":"ABC","ID":"T001"},"1":{"yr":2018,"PKID":"1234,54321","Subject":"XYZ","ID":"T002"}}
print [{k: v} for k, v in d.items()]
```

**Output:**

```
[{'1': {'PKID': '1234,54321', 'yr': 2018, 'ID': 'T002', 'Subject': 'XYZ'}}, {'0': {'PKID': '58306, 57011', 'yr': 2017, 'ID': 'T001', 'Subject': 'ABC'}}]
```

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

```
from operator import itemgetter

d = {"0":{"yr":2017,"PKID":"58306, 57011","Subject":"ABC","ID":"T001"},"1":
    {"yr":2018,"PKID":"1234,54321","Subject":"XYZ","ID":"T002"}}

sorted_d = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: int(x[0]))

print(list(map(itemgetter(1), sorted_d)))
```

Which Outputs:

```
[{'yr': 2017, 'PKID': '58306, 57011', 'Subject': 'ABC', 'ID': 'T001'}, 
 {'yr': 2018, 'PKID': '1234,54321', 'Subject': 'XYZ', 'ID': 'T002'}]
```