# How to effeciently convert dictionary of Lists into Pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, dictionary, data-conversion

I would like to convert dictionary of Lists into Pandas dataframe. While there are many (which can lead to downvote) similar topic such as [OP1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50345062/6446053),[OP2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49027872/6446053), [OP3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20638006/6446053), [OP4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53555487/6446053), [OP5](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40973211/6446053), [OP6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29815129/6446053), but none of the suggestion worked for me. Off all, the closes suggestion I got was from the [OP7](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50345062/6446053). However, the following error was shot

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'
```

The mock up dictionary that represent the actual dictionary are as below:

```
x_00 = [{ "brand": "Ford","model": "Mustang","year": 1964},
            {  "brand": "Fx","model": "Musxxg","year": 1900},
          {"brand" : "Foyy", "model": "Musyyy", "year": 2020 }]

x_01= [{ "brand": "Forr","model": "Musrr","year": 1900},
            {  "brand": "Frr","model": "Musrr","year": 1955},
          {"brand" : "Forr", "model": "Musrr", "year": 2025 }]

x_02= [{ "brand": "Fogg","model": "Musgg","year": 1902},
            {  "brand": "Fgg","model": "Musgg","year": 1922},
          {"brand" : "Fogg", "model": "Musgg", "year": 2022 }]

CombineAll=[x_00,x_01,x_02]
```

As per suggestion from the thread  [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50345062/6446053) , the following code was realized.

```
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame.from_dict(x, orient='index') for x in CombineAll])
```

But as mentioned above, error was thrown out.

Really appreciate for any hint or direction to any thread that I might miss look.

**I am glad to delete this thread if there is possible duplicate!**

Comment: `pd.concat([*map(pd.DataFrame,CombineAll)],ignore_index=True)` ?

Comment: ```df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(data=x) for x in CombineAll])``` works as x is a list, not dict

Comment: combineAll = x_00 + x_01+ x_02 , df= pd.Dataframe(combinAll)

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(x_00+x_01+x_02)` or if you have a list of list: `pd.DataFrame(*reduce(lambda cum_list, new_list: cum_list + new_list,CombineAll ))`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @anky. I check the other thread and found that the solution provided there is different than your. Because of this,  I think you should post your suggestion as an answer rather than comment to get the proper credit!

Comment: Also, is it still dont consider my thread as a duplicate thread compare to the said other thread? mmm

Comment: @balandongiv its essentially the same question :) best not to have multiple questions for the same purpose? piR has commented down the answer the same as mine as well.

Comment: noted @anky. Thanks btw